# How to get username?

Tags: botframework

I am creating a simple skype chat bot. I have noticed some bots in the directory can reference my username and/or firstname/lastname, without the bot needing to ask.

How do I retrieve the username of the user in skype (or any other channel), without asking the user?

Comment: Please don't forget to select an answer for your question to help other developers.

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out. In NodeJS use session.message.user.name

```
intents.matches('Start', function (session, args) {
    session.send("Hi " + session.message.user.name);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
//In C# you can use following code for getting username

   private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    string userName
    activity = context.Activity;
    if(activity.From.Name != null)
    {
        userName = activity.From.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**NodeJS**

```
intents.matches('Start', function (session, args) {
    session.send("Hi " + session.message.user.name);
});
```

**C#**

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    string userName
    activity = context.Activity;
    if(activity.From.Name != null)
    {
        userName = activity.From.Name;
    }
}
```

Since no runtime language was specified, combining answers for both languages from other responses.